# How to model the scope of a database transaction within an UML activity diagram?

Tags: database, transactions, uml, activity-diagram

I need to model a process, the required notation is an UML activity diagram.

An input file is read and for each line a database record would be batch-inserted, but only if all lines of the input file pass some validity checks.  If any line violates the validation rules, the entire input file would be rejected.

This seems like a very common pattern, however, the only graphical way of modelling this seems to be modelling begin and end of the transaction as activities. [image: modelling begin and end of transaction as activities]

Isn't there a way to do this more nicely? 
Is there a UML or SysML language element that corresponds to a looped transaction?
The diagram is intended for a non-tech customer who would be very confused by the transaction activites.

Answer (score 0):

Structured Activity Nodes have been around in UML (though I have to admit the completely passed my attention so far). The current 2.5 Spec says on p. 477:

> **Loop Nodex**
>
> A LoopNode is a StructuredActivityNode that represents an iterative loop. A LoopNode consists of a setupPart, a test and a bodyPart, which identify subsets of the ExecutableNodes contained in the LoopNode. Any ExecutableNode in the LoopNode must be included in the setupPart, test or bodyPart for the LoopNode.

On p. 478:

> **Notation**
>
> A StructuredActivityNode is notated with a dashed round cornered rectangle enclosing its nodes and edges, with the keyword «structured» at the top.
>
> [image]
>
> No standard notation is defined for ConditionalNodes, LoopNodes or SequenceNodes.

Note the last sentence. The notation for this has been expanded in 2.5. But honestly I would not use it much here and look into BPMN instead, which is a UML based profile that has become more wide spread. I'd rather stay with basic UML notation like this unless you use BPMN:

[image]

There are two activities `Process File` (to the left) and `Process Line` (as diagram frame to the right). The latter is used as invocation in the first activity.

Comment: Its is true that the loop activity node needs to have a dashed border. Thanks. http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/standard_uml_models/loop_and_conditional_nodes2.html

Comment: BPMN is a very useful tool, indeed. But for modelling software-internal issues... I mean there is no real business logic in this process, apart from the notion of a database transaction... I guess the question really is how to explain the technical concept of a transaction to a non-tech customer. Maybe there just is no way to achieve this ;-)

Comment: You might take whatever helps to communicate. So basically you can also go with what you have chosen in first place. I mean, if you are not fluent in a language you sometimes use "wrong" words or syntax, but people understand what you mean anyway. Of course, getting more fluent will improve communication.